# Can I include the date range that a weekly summary alert covers?

Tags: 2013, alert, email-templates

We have a request to include the date range that a weekly summary alert covers in either the subject (preferred) or body of the email.

We know that we can create a custom `alerttemplates.xml` in `C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\XML`, and we have, but trying to find what parameters can be pulled in hasn't been as easy.

Is it possible to pull the start and end dates into the email, so we could have something to the effect of "Weekly Summary for the week of February 3rd" or "Weekly Summary for 2/3/2014-2/9/2014?"

Note that we'd rather do as much as we can with the standard SharePoint 2013 functionality, and are therefore staying away from alert handlers at this point. But if that's the only way to do this, we'll pursue that in our next phase.

Thanks!